# How to CUDA-ize code when all cores require global memory access

Tags: memory, parallel-processing, cuda

Without CUDA, my code is just two for loops that calculate the distance between all pairs of coordinates in a system and sort those distances into bins.

The problem with my CUDA version is that apparently threads can't write to the same global memory locations at the same time (race conditions?).  The values I end up getting for each bin are incorrect because only one of the threads ended up writing to each bin.

```
__global__ void computePcf(
        double const * const atoms,
        double * bins,
        int numParticles,
        double dr) {

    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < numParticles - 1) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numParticles; j++) {
            double r = distance(&atoms[3*i + 0], &atoms[3*j + 0]);

            int binNumber = floor(r/dr);

            // Problem line right here.
            // This memory address is modified by multiple threads
            bins[binNumber] += 2.0;
        }
    }
}
```

So... I have no clue what to do.  I've been Googling and reading about shared memory, but the problem is that I don't know what memory area I'm going to be accessing until I do my distance computation!

I know this is possible, because a program called VMD uses the GPU to speed up this computation.  Any help (or even ideas) would be greatly appreciated.  I don't need this optimized, just functional.

Answer (score 1):

How many `bins[]` are there?
Is there some reason that `bins[]` need to be of type `double`?  It's not obvious from your code.  What you have is essentially a [histogram](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs344/Lesson_3_-_Fundamental_GPU_Algorithms_%28Reduce,_Scan,_Histogram%29) operation, and you may want to look at fast parallel histogram techniques.   [Thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/source/browse/examples/histogram.cu) may be of interest.

There are several possible avenues to consider with your code:

1. See if there is a way to restructure your algorithm to arrange computations in such a way that a given group of threads (or bin computations) are not stepping on each other.  This might be accomplished based on sorting distances, perhaps.
2. Use [atomics](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions)  This should solve your problem, but will likely be costly in terms of execution time (but since it's so simple you might want to give it a try.) In place of this:

   ```
   bins[binNumber] += 2.0;
   ```

   Something like this:

   ```
   int * bins,
   ...
   atomicAdd(bins+binNumber, 2);
   ```

   You can still do this if `bins` are of type `double`, it's just a bit more complicated.  Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) for the example of how to do `atomicAdd` on a `double`.
3. If the number of `bins` is small (maybe a few thousand, or less) then you could create a few sets of bins that are updated by multiple threadblocks, and then use a reduction operation (adding the sets of bins together, element by element) at the end of the processing sequence.  In this case, you might want to consider using a smaller number of threads or threadblocks, each of which processes multiple elements, by putting an additional loop in your kernel code, so that after each particle processing is complete, the loop jumps to the next particle by adding `gridDim.x*blockDim.x` to the `i` variable, and repeating the process.  Since each thread or threadblock has it's own local copy of the bins, it can do this without stepping on other threads accesses.

   For example, suppose I only needed 1000 bins of type int.  I could create 1000 sets of bins, which would only take up about 4 megabytes.  I could then give each of 1000 threads it's own bin set, and then each of the 1000 threads would have it's own bin set to update, and would not require atomics, since it could not interfere with any other thread.  By having each thread loop through multiple particles, I can still effectively keep the machine busy this way.  When all the particle-binning is done, I then have to add my 1000 bin-sets together, perhaps with a separate kernel call.